# PHP Capitalizing

Tags: php, capitalization

I not only need to capitalize the first letter in my string but also the 5th.

How would you capitalize the string "RoadAtlanta" properly?

Comment: Are you looking to capitalize any arbitrary list of words and joining them, or are you specifically just wanting to use those two words?

Comment: That string is already correctly capitalized by your rules.

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to chars by their index:

```
$string[4] = strtoupper($string[4]);
```

4 in this particular case refers to 5th character. String characters are indexed from 0 as arrays so you can directly refer to characters at particular position.

Comment: Note that `{}` is the deprecated way, you should use `[]` instead

Comment: Thanks ioseb but how would i do positions 0 and 4?

Comment: `ucfirst()` will handle the first character.